# Using two different GPUs for display and rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, gpu, windows, system

In the GPU Rendering manual https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

it states that when rendering heavy scenes on the GPU it is best to have two different gpus: One for the display output and windows only and the other gpu for the rendering.

Let's say i have a computer with a rtx 3090 for rendering and another lets say 3060 only for the display.

Would this kind of setup be more reliable when rendering in the viewport?

Anyone have experience with this kind of setup?

Answer (score 2):

In that case, You'd have your monitor plugged into the 3060 and the Optix render device set to the 3090. (No CPU or other GPU. 90% of the time, adding the CPU will slow down your render.)

I assume you're trying to take the load off of your main GPU while rendering. In that case, Blender actually stops the viewport render when you start a render(Unless you move/update the viewport after). Also, checking "Lock Interface" under the Render tab in the Header lowers the risk of crashing Blender and theoretically saves memory.[image: Lock Interface Screenshot]